# Why is the MRO seemingly different between Python 3.7 and 3.10 with multiple inheritance involving int and calling str()?

Tags: python

I ran into some issues when I updated a codebase from Python 3.7.5 to 3.10.
As I understand inheritance should have the order of left to right meaning if you inherit from two classes then it should use the left classes method. And it was the case in 3.7.5, however in Python 3.10 if you first inherit form int or float and you add a second class to the inheritance list (in my case Base) then it will use that Base's `__str__` method while `__repr__` method works as expected.

Am I missing something? Is this a bug?

```
class Base:
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return 'Base'
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return 'Base'
    
class Integer(int, Base):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        return int.__new__(cls, value)

class String(str, Base):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        return str.__new__(cls, value)  

print(f"str: {Integer(2)} and {String(2)}")
print(f"repr: {repr(Integer(2))} and {repr(String(2))}")
```

In Python 3.7.5 it prints:

```
str: 2 and 2
repr: 2 and '2'
```

In Python 3.10 and 3.11 it prints:

```
str: Base and 2
repr: 2 and '2'
```

Comment: Did you try 3.8 or 3.9?

Comment: It seems like from 3.8 and onwards this is the behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Integer` class's MRO goes `(Integer, int, Base, object)`, giving priority to methods defined in `int` over those defined in `Base`, but `int` doesn't actually define `__str__`. It defines `__repr__`, but it inherits `object.__str__`. It only looks like it defines `__str__` because `object.__str__` delegates to `__repr__`, which `int` does define.

So, if you call `str(Integer(2))`, it doesn't find an implementation in `Integer` or `int`. The first implementation it finds is `Base.__str__`, which returns `'Base'`.

The behavior is different on Python 3.7.5 because on newer Python versions, `int.__format__` calls `str(self)` when the format spec is empty. On older versions, it uses a separate formatting implementation, which doesn't end up calling any methods you defined.